# How to authenticate my laravel webpage after a successfull login using laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel-7, laravel-passport, laravel-api

I have created a laravel api with passport autentication. I have the following front-end login that works perpectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
    $("#loginfrm").on("submit", function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var dcookie = document.cookie;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://api-auth.test/api/auth/login",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN" : '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + "{{ Cookie::get('laravel_token') }}",
            },
            data:{
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                "username": username,
                "password": password
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                if (data.responseJSON["authstat"] == "Authorized")
                {
                    window.location.href = "http://api-auth.test/employees";
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(data.responseJSON["authstat"]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
      
</script>
```

And my API `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::prefix('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register'); 
    Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
});
```

**Consuming my own api:**

My problem is, when my application redirects to `"http://api-auth.test/employees"`, the page is not really authenticated. Below is my `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/inbox', function () {
    return view('pages.employees');
});
```

Then I tried to encapsulate my route as what I have search here in stackoverflow:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::get('/inbox', function () {
        return view('pages.employees');
    });
});
```

And it returns an error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [login] not defined.
```

I found out that the error occur in `Middleware/Authenticate.php` and I dont know what to do with it.

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
   if (!($request->expectsJson())) {
       return route('login');
   }
}
```

I just want to display the list of Employee when it redirects to `http://api-auth.test/employees` for testing purposes. here is my `EmployeeController`:

```
public function index()
{
  $employee = Employee::all();

  return response()->json([
      "success" => true,
      "message" => "Employee List",
      "data" => $employee
  ]);
}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Apply "auth" middleware not "auth:api"

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/inbox', function () {
      return view('pages.employees');
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a way of resolving this error? "Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route [login] not defined."  I already tried your suggestion but still returns and error.